# Defining a SQL Server rule with LIKE

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to use `LIKE` when defining a rule for a UDDT in SQL Server? If yes - how?

I tried but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE RULE RU_NAME AS @value = '^[A-Z][a-z]*';
GO

CREATE TYPE DT_NAME FROM VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL;
GO

EXEC sys.sp_bindrule @rulename = N'[dbo].[RU_NAME]', 
                     @objname = N'[dbo].[DT_NAME]', 
                     @futureonly = 'futureonly';
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OLT35A006T]
(
     [PFD_NAME] [dbo].[DT_NAME]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: [`RULE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-rule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)s are deprecated, don't use them at all. As for User defined scalar types, these are just alias types; they don't allow for validation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-rule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-creating-a-rule-with-a-pattern

Comment: @lptr Did you notice the warning at the top of the page though?

Comment: Also alias types should be avoided anyway - they are great until you need to change your `varchar(64)` for example to _anything else_. Then you’ll be crying. See https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE RULE`is deprecated, you should use a regular `CHECK` constraint instead. And UDDTs, better known as *alias types*, have [their own issues](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types).

> Note that SQL Server does not support Regex, you need `LIKE`

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OLT35A006T]
(
     [PFD_NAME] varchar(64) NOT NULL, CHECK (PFD_NAME LIKE '[A-Z]%' AND PFD_NAME NOT LIKE '[A-Z]%[^a-z]%')
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e425139c394ef0626b483f75dc2af46)